# How to get an array field from an object when embedding mono

Tags: c#, c, mono, interop, mono-embedding

I am embedding mono into an application i'm writing. One of the objects I have created looks like this:

```
public class MessageObject
{
  public byte messagetype;
  public byte[] message;
}
```

If i use `mono_field_get_value_object` I can get a `MonoObject *` that represents the message array, but How can I access it like an array? Is there some explicit cast to `MonoArray *`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Explicitly cast `MonoObject *` to `MonoArray *`, and then simply use the functions as documented [here](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=xhtml%3adeploy%2fmono-api-object.html).